# How to get Flask app to run locally after exporting secret key as an environment variable?

Tags: python, flask, secret-key

I built an app with Flask on macOS using PyCharm and created a virtual environment for this project. First, I generated a new secret key inside local (.venv) terminal:
`python -c 'import secrets; print(secrets.token_hex())'`

I then set `app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = "secret-token-output-from-terminal-as-above"` that enables the flask app to run smoothly.

But as soon as I export SECRET_KEY (e.g., set it as an environment variable) and `import os`, the app does not work. I keep getting **RuntimeError: A secret key is required to use CSRF.**

`import os`

`app = Flask(__name__)`

`app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = os.environ.get("SECRET_KEY")`

[image]

In the local terminal of the project .venv, I entered `env` which gives this output: [image]

I ran main.py with `print(os.environ.get("SECRET_KEY"))` which gives `None`

Same output `None` within console.[image]

This means that if I decide to export SECRET_KEY from within my project directory (.venv), then it gets erased as soon as I close that terminal session? Where should I keep the SECRET_KEY so that my flask app can work?

Comment: Where are you setting `app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = "secret-token-output-from-terminal-as-above"`? In your example you're setting `app.config['SECRET_KEY']` to the value of an environment variable, but you haven't shown us how you're setting that environment variable.

Comment: app.config is set inside main.py - picture added.

Comment: I still don't see where you're setting the `SECRET_KEY` environment variable: this would be somewhere *outside* of your Python code. Have you verified that `os.getenv('SECRET_KEY')` is returning the value you expect?

Comment: I ran main.py with `print(os.environ.get("SECRET_KEY"))` and this returned `None`

Comment: You can use export SECRET_KEY=<secret_key> <commands to run your server>

Comment: The output of your `print(os.environ.get("SECRET_KEY"))` means that `SECRET_KEY` is not available in the environment in which you Python code is running. How are you starting the code -- from the command line (in the same terminal in which you ran `env`), or via some other mechanism?